# Laravel 5 and Socialite - Require Email Address from Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

Does anyone know how to set the "Email Address" as mandatory when a user logins in via Facebook using Socialite (if it is possible)?

At the moment my integration allows the user to remove the Email Address from the data that will be shared by Facebook on the Facebook side.

While we don't currently use the email address to contact the user, we do use it for matching accounts together if they login via different methods. This makes the site easier for the user overall.

If this is not possible then in the long run I may need to revoke the users access if they don't share the email address in order to avoid data issues. However I will hopefully be able to avoid this.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Cs1h

Comment: Not every user even _has_ an email address on file with Facebook – for example lots of users that used only their mobile to sign up.

Answer (score 2):

You can't explicitly require it, it's up to the user to share it or not when authorizing so you need to build your application to support this.

In my opinion if they don't choose to share the email then you should detect this and have a page that asks them to enter it manually and send them an activation link to confirm their account before linking.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I thought that might be the case but I just wanted to confirm it. I will look into requesting it after authorisation if they have not provided it.